# Getting value from select to pass as variable in URL in AJAX script

Tags: jquery, ajax, select

I am using the following ajax script to pass variables to a PHP script:

```
<script>
    function showUser(str)
    {
        if (str == "")
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/scripts/notes.php?s=2&q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

At the moment the variable 's' is just set to 2, but I would like to set this dynamically using the current value in a select on the page:

```
<select id='sessions'>
<option value='5'>5 sessions</option>
<option value='10'>10 sessions</option>
<option value='1000'>All sessions</option>
</select>
```

I have tried using:

```
var sessions= $("#sessions").val();
```

in the above script before the URL is set, and then changing 's=2' to 's=sessions', but the correct value isn't being passed (I suspect s is being passed as empty).

What do I need to change to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> changing 's=2' to 's=sessions'

Setting your string to `"/scripts/notes.php?s=session&q="` will not pass the variable. Try `"/scripts/notes.php?s=" + session + "&q="`.

```
function showUser(str)
{
    var sessions= $("#sessions").val();

    if (str == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/scripts/notes.php?s="+sessions+"&q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```